# Does the module() function still exist?

Tags: lua

A colleague tells me that the module() function of lua has been removed.  On his Windows machine when he types "module" at the lua prompt 'nil' is returned.  Yet on a linux box also running lua 5.3.4 at the lua prompt the symbol 'module' is

```
$ lua
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> module
function: 0x55ff43068b20
>
```

Can anybody help explain this seeming contradiction?

Comment: Yes, Linux version of Lua has a lot of outdated functions by default.  See compilation flags in makefile.  Scripts building Lua in Windows usually don't define those compatibility flags.